# K-means clustering - weird PCA visualization

Tags: clustering, pca, k-means

I performed PCA on 4 variables and are shown in this visualization:
[image]

At first look it doesn't look convincing and the some clusters seem weird.
The data was cleaned and standardized beforehand. Only continues variables with plausible skew were used.

Used variables:

- PURCHASES:  Amount of purchases made using the account
- ONEOFF_PURCHASES:  Maximum amount spent on a single one-off purchase
- INSTALLMENTS_PURCHASES: Amount of purchases made in installments
- CASH_ADVANCE: Amount paid in advance by the customer

When analyzing relative importance the outcomes make sense:
[image]

Distributions:
[image]
Distributions before standarization:
[image]
Can I draw some conclusion from this graph? Are my clusters wrong?

Comment: What are the four variables?

Comment: Hi, I updated the post

Comment: The distributions look like they have sharp peaks around a low value. Do these correspond to zero values in the non-standardized data, or placeholder values for missing data?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for help. It correspond to zero value. I'll update the post.

Comment: If a large number of accounts are never used to make a purchase it might make sense to handle these separately, maybe try to find out why no purchase was made. Without the zero values the distributions look approximately normal, so PCA should work well on the remaining data.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you. I'll try it and post the results later :)